# How to seperate last two digits with dot in Python

Tags: python

I always want to separate the last two digits with a decimal point . (dot)L

```
print("{:.2f}".format(300));
```

Output:

```
300.00
```

Expected output:

```
3.00
```

Next

```
print("{:.2f}".format(333333300));
```

Output:

```
333333300.00
```

Expected output:

```
3333333.00
```

How can I change my code so that I get the expected output instead?

Comment: Why would you expect Python to format 300 as 3.00? They are different numbers. Formatting can only change the *representation* of the number, not the value of it.

Comment: @Mounarajan that's how the language it's suppose to work. The precision you are giving work works on floats i.e. 300.34546 then the 2 digit precision will print 300.34 if you give it an int it will add two zeros like 300.00

Comment: Divide the number by 100 first??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`300.00` is a representation of number `300`. `3.00` is a representation of number `3`. Those are two different values. There is no way Python will represent `300` as `3`.

Assuming you really want to print `3.00` (which for pretty much everyone around means `3`, not `300`), then you should divide `300` by `100`.

```
print("{:.2f}".format(300/100.0))
```

Comment: if i use this print("{:.2f}".format(2990/100)) i get this output 29.00 but expected is 29.90

Comment: Right. You're using Python 2 and 300/100 is interpreted as integer division. You should divide by 100.0 to force float division. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the number value you actually want to output, i.e. don't add the '0' you want in the string representation.

```
print("{:.2f}".format(3))
```

It is the string formatting which does add the '0' for you when it creates the string representation of the number value, depending on the specified formatting string.

Comment: if i use this print("{:.2f}".format(2990)) i get this output 2990.00
 but expected is 29.90

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    a = divmod(n,100)
    if a[1] < 10:
         print("{}.0{}".format(a[0],a[1]))
    else:
        print("{}.{}".format(a[0],a[1]))
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would increase the quality of your post.

Comment: divmod(a,b).Take two (non complex) numbers as arguments and return a pair of numbers consisting of their quotient and remainder when using long division。the result is the same as (a // b, a % b).The tuple a[0] gets a // b,a[1] gets a % b. if a[1] < 10,such as 3001,3009, a[1] will be 1 and 9 ,so when formating ,it should add an 0

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.6 :

```
def myPrint(x):
    print("{0:.2f}".format(x/100.00));

myPrint(2990);
```

29.90